# Could Not Load NiB in bundle, tried EVERYTHING but still get this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xib

I tried to create a custom UITableViewCell, but I started getting the following error:

```
    2013-06-25 03:56:53.435 Ma-Goal[3372:19d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
    exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
    'NSBundle </Users/Library/Application Support/iPhone 
    Simulator/6.1/Applications/7BAEEE5A-535C-40AB-93F2-FF4B34CF7644/APP.app> (loaded)'
    with name 'p4f-GK-Fuy-view-CLd-MQ-Lha''
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x24cd012 0x22f2e7e 0x24ccdeb 0x1452ef9 0x13177e7 0x1317dc8 0x146628e 0x6f650  
    0x1317ff8 0x1318232 0x146605b 0x77b0 0x1453a36 0x1562a02 0x15620e5 0x14535c8 0x1453d2c 
    0x1562a02 0x1562418 0x15620e5 0x14529f0 0x167e54a 0x167e6c3 0x123671e 0x12369a2 
    0x1235876 0x1246cb5 0x1247beb 0x1239698 0x2e83df9 0x2e83ad0 0x2442bf5 0x2442962         
    0x2473bb6 0x2472f44 0x2472e1b 0x123517a 0x1236ffc 0x255d 0x2485)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I read all the other questions and answers about this problem, and I even tried each and every suggested solution, none of it worked.

I checked the targets were matched and the copy bundle resources had the files included, I reseted and cleaned all of XCode settings and iPhone Simulator settings, I removed references to the .xib file that gave me the problem, and eventually, I even deleted it.

I completely stopped using the UITableViewCell file in my UIViewController that caused the problem, but I still get this error. My code is exactly the way it was before I added that dreaded .xib file for the UITableViewCell, but this error won't go away. What am I doing wrong??? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: put the code how are you loading it  >

Comment: I'm not loading it anymore, I deleted all the files that had to do with the .xib, I have no .xib files in my project at all!!

Comment: check your xib-file: Open, Reconnect all outlets (delete all and then connect).

Comment: there is no xib file to reconnect outlets to though, i completely deleted it from the project =(, i'm completely stumped!!

Comment: Well then you have your answer. You have no xib file to load.

Comment: check Xcode project. Remove all resources which is red color.

Comment: I STILL get the same error tho, which is why I'm completely confused... and there are no red colored resources

Comment: Check your Xcode project whether it hast a main interface set. That is an XIB, if any. You may need to check for iPhone and iPad if the app is universal.

Comment: Plus clean your project and delete it from all simulators and devices before re-building it.

Comment: recreate Xcode project and then add your files again

Comment: Well, recreating my project worked, thanks!